# How to numerically search for all closest-to-zero values in an Matlab array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I've got some numerical data of a positive function with a number of "zeros", however, none of these zeros is ever exactly zero.  I'd like to extract the positions of all these zero values, and was wondering what the best way to do it was.  Here's a contrived example that is similar to what I'd like to solve, with an illustrative plot of the values, the adjacent differences, and the signs of those differences:

```
a = [ 0.0062 ; 0.0041 ; 0.0021 ; 0.0003 ; 0.0015 ; 0.0031 ; 0.0045 ; 0.0059 ; 0.0062 ; 0.0041 ; 0.0021 ; 0.0003 ; 0.0015 ; 0.0031 ; 0.0045 ; 0.0059 ]/0.0062 ;
d = diff(a) ;

r = -3/2:0.5:length(a)/2-4/2 ;

close all ;
hold on ;

plot( r, a ) ;
plot( r(1:length(d)), d ) ;
plot( r(1:length(d)), sign(d) ) ;
```

Which produces:

[image: zeros]

Based on what I've done, I could iterate over the array and find all the places that the sign of the difference array changes from -1, to 1.  Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to do that than a for-loop?
2. Is there a better way to do this sort of search for all miniumums?

Comment: So with your example `a` what would the desired result be?

Comment: If you have a specific tolerance you could try using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html). e.g. `idx = find(abs(a) < tolerance)`

Comment: The array indexes that contain the 0.003/0.0062 values.  The corresponding values in the numerical range r are really what I'm after, but I can do that final mapping myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To **find values at which the difference changes from positive to negative**:

```
indices = find(diff(sign(diff(a)))==2)+1;
```

In your example this gives

```
indices =
     4
    12
```

---

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could **find the closest-to-zero value(s)** directly as follows:

```
b = abs(a);
indices = find(b==min(b))
```

which also gives

```
indices =
     4
    12
```

Note that this will find *the* index of the value that is closest to zero, unless there is a tie between several values, in which case it returns *several* indices.

Comment: Your first method works well.  The second won't for my data, since the minimum isn't guarenteed to be the same at each "zero".

Comment: @PeeterJoot Good point. I've edited the answer to make it clear to potential readers that the second method generally returns only one value

Answer (score 0):

What about take `your_data`, do `1./your_data` and then use `findpeaks`. See the documentation for more options on `findpeaks` including the possibility to give treshold value for lowest peak to find. It should help.

Comment: I don't appear to have purchased the signal processing toolbox.